# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do a codewars task in TypeScript, but I am running into the error in the title. I assume the problem is that I need to define the type of the object I am passing into my reduce function, but I don't know what the signature should be.

```
export function duplicateEncode(word: string): string{
    const counts = word.split('').reduce((acc, val) => {
        if (val in acc){
            acc[val] += 1;
        } else{
            acc[val] = 1;
        }
        return acc;
        }, {})
    return word.split('').map(char => counts[char] == 1 ? '(' : ')').join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the type of the accumulator by defining a variable:

```js
export function duplicateEncode(word: string): string {
  const acc: { [key: string]: number } = {};
  const counts = word.split('').reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (val in acc) {
      acc[val] += 1;
    } else {
      acc[val] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, acc);
  return word.split('').map(char => counts[char] == 1 ? '(' : ')').join('');
}
```

The type `{ [key: string]: number }` is an object where keys are strings and values are numbers.

You can also assert the type inline:

```js
const counts = word.split('').reduce((acc, val) => {
  ...
  return acc;
}, {} as { [key: string]: number });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have any string (character) as key, so `{ [key: string] : number }` should do the trick:

```js
export function duplicateEncode(word: string): string{
    const acc: { [key: string] : number } = {} 

    const counts = word.split('').reduce((acc, val) => {
        if (val in acc){
            acc[val] += 1;
        } else{
            acc[val] = 1;
        }
        return acc;
        }, acc)

    return word.split('').map(char => counts[char] == 1 ? '(' : ')').join('');
}
```